# Data is been sent from client but not reached in server angular2 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, client-server

I am trying to  post my form data to server(node) but it is not getting reached there when i put console to data in backend it says undefined.Data is been sent from client but not reached in server.I think i am wrong at headers,can any one please suggest help.
my ts,

```
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.http.post(this.header1+'login', JSON.stringify(form), { headers: headers })
```

my server,

```
exports.login = function( req, res ) {
 console.log("Params:"+req.body.email);
  //console.log('email:'+params.email);
  var query = 'select * from profile where email = ? and password = ?'; 
 connection.query(query,[req.body.email,req.body.password],function(error,result,rows,fields){
    if(!!error){console.log(error)
      console.log('fail');
    }else{
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    }
  // }

  });}
```

my routes(express)

```
 router.post('/login', admin.login);
```

Answer (score 0):

`http` uses `Observable` and observables are lazy. They don't actually execute anything unless subscribed to.

You need either

```
this.http.post(this.header1+'login', JSON.stringify(form), { headers: headers })
.subscribe(response => console.log(response.json());

this.http.post(this.header1+'login', JSON.stringify(form), { headers: headers })
.toPromise();
```

to make `http` send the request.

Comment: Hi gunter, there is no  problem with client the data is not going to the server

Comment: Why are you so sure the problem is not on the client. If the client doesn't send anything it's expected that the server doesn't get anything, isn't it? Do you actually call `subscribe()` or `toPromise()` on the observable you get from `http.post()`?

Comment: i see the json type data in network but i am not recieving it on server i bthink so....................

Comment: Ok, your question doesn't show it and it's a common issue. If the client actually sends the request and you don't get an error on the client, than a connection to the server has been established successfully and the server accepted the data. Either just your handler on the server is not called when it receives a call or the client connects with a different server ;-)